# Flip animation between two views on iOS

Tags: ios

I have an app that uses the built-in flip animation to switch between the various views.  Everything works, except when I'm flipping back to a view that was a scroll view and it was NOT on the first page.  Meaning:

- My scroll view has three pages
- User swipes to the third page
- User taps the button on the third page to proceed to the next view
- when user tries to return to the scroll view the flip animation shows the first page during the flip and then snaps to the correct page after the flip is done.

I'm using [scrollView setContentOffset] to the set the correct page BEFORE the flip animation but that doesn't seem to be enough.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: you could provide some code... there are many ways you can be doing what you describe...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
[scrollView setContentOffset:theOffset animated:NO];
```

You want to suppress animations, since you are performing an animation yourself. You also want to be sure that you set the content offset BEFORE you begin specifying the flip animation, since the animation transforms everything from the current state to whatever new values you provide in the animation block.

Calling it in `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear:` should work.

Comment: Thanks.  The issue was indeed starting the animation before the view was set -- I just moved the animation start code and everything fell into place.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility you could check is using `setContentOffset`:

```
[scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(pageWidth * pageNumber, 0)];
```

to move the scrollView origin so that it display page number `pageNumber` (raging from 0 to N). Or you could try with:

```
- (void)setContentOffset:(CGPoint)contentOffset animated:(BOOL)animated
```

but since you do not specify how you do the flip animation, I don't know which one will work for you.

Comment: Thank you.  Let me elaborate: I do use setContentOffset to jump to the correct page, BUT, that doesn't do the trick.  Right now, the views flip and I see the first page of the scrollView during the flip -- as soon as the flip is finished, the scrollView snaps to the correct page.  I'm trying to see if there is a way to see the correct page during the flip.  I'll update my original post to reflect this issue (thank you again).

Comment: where do you call `setContentOffset`? possibly you have to call it in the `viewWillAppear` method of the controller that manages the scroll view...

Comment: Initially in viewDidLoad.  Then I did it in viewDidAppear and I also tried to do it in both place.  It seems like it should work: viewDidLoad and viewDidAppear are called in order before the flip begins and the page offset is set correctly.  But the flip itself still shows the first page.  Then at the end of the flip viewDidAppear gets called again which again sets the page number and at that point the view snaps to the correct page.